# Probabilistic quantile of an empiric distribution

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, quantile-function

Given $N$ samples $x_1,\dots, x_n$ with mean $\bar x$ and variance $s^2$ drawn from a normally distributed process with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$. I also have a variable $0 < p < 1,$

I would like to determine the value $v$ such that $P(x_{n+1} > v) = p$

As $N$ goes to infinity, $v$ goes to the result of the corresponding [quantile function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Quantile_function) for a normal random variable with mean $\bar x$ and variance $s^2,$ but if $N$ is small enough, the fact that $\bar x \ne\mu$ and $s^s\ne\sigma^2$  has to be taken into account. How exactly do I do that?

Comment: I'm a little confused. If each $x_i$ is drawn form a normal distribution, what role does $n$ play?

Comment: If n is small, the measured mean and standard deviation aren't necessarily the same as those of the actual distribution (which you'd get if n->infinity). This gap should be taken into account.

Let's say I take p=0.8, so I want to find v such that the next sample I'll take has an 80% chance of being larger than v.

If n is very big, I can confidently use the quantile function, but if n=3, I'll have to take a smaller value to account for the possibility that the mean I measured is larger than the actual mean of the distribution.

Comment: Oh, I understand. $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ measure the sample mean and variance. Just a heads up, its a bit confusing to use $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ this way. Generally, we use $\bar{x}$ and $s^2$ for sample mean and variance and $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ for the population mean and variance. To be honest, I"m not sure your question has a definite answer as stated. I think you'd need to state a prior distribution over values of the population mean and variance in order to answer this question, but maybe someone else knows better.

Comment: You are probably right. I knew something is missing, but didn't think about the prior distribution of the population mean and variance. Thanks for the input!